# Como evitar que o console seja executando duas vezes?

Tags: ide, prompt

Tenho tido esse mesmo problema em outros computadores meus, e inclusive, em outras IDE's também. Acontece o seguinte:

Quando termino de escrever meu código C e o executo, primeiramente aparece um *prompt* por mais ou menos 5 segundos. Eu consigo testar o código dentro deste tempo limite, porém, passados os 5 segundos ele fecha com ou sem meu consentimento.

Após isso, abre-se novamente um segundo *prompt* com a execução do código se iniciando do 0. Desta vez, este *prompt* não possui limite de tempo como o anterior.

Isso torna o processo de testes mais demorado, porque o *prompt* é executado duas vezes ao invés de uma. Pode não parecer grande coisa, mas depois de certo tempo isso se torna extremamente irritante.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que é e como resolver isso?

Atualmente uso o Visual Studio Express 2013.

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Vou arriscar que você possui o **Avast** como antivírus, acertei? Veja se [essas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888867/visual-studio-executable-run-twice) ou [essas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice) respostas resolvem. Ou então, [essa](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/dc839484-de0e-47c0-b8dc-d240a1259a0c/why-does-my-console-open-twice-when-i-run) pergunta no Dev-center da Microsoft. Em todas é apontado o antivírus (sendo mais especifico: Avast) como responsável por esse comportamento.

Comment: Renan, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Era isso mesmo. Fiz os testes após desabilitar o Deep Screen do Avast Anti-vírus, e esse problema parou de acontecer.

Me diga: Sou novo por aqui. Existe alguma forma de eu pontuar sua resposta ou algo do tipo? Nada mais justo, afinal de contas, você me ajudou.

Comment: Nem se preocupe com isso, pra mim a reputação é o de menos. Só de saber que ajudei já vale mais que a pontuação. Se quiser, pode publicar uma resposta explicando como resolveu, com detalhes. Futuramente outros usuários que estiverem passando pelo mesmo problema poderão encontrar sua resposta. **:D**